# Postgis ST_Intersects behaves erratically

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am using Postgres 13.0 on a Mac, with Postgis 3.0. I encountered a problem where ST_Intersects produces the wrong result, and after narrowing it down, I arrived at the following:

With the following table created:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    name VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    area GEOGRAPHY NOT NULL
);
```

I insert a row:

```
INSERT INTO test (name, area) 
VALUES('test1', 
        ST_GeogFromText('POLYGON((-80 -60,-100 -60,-120 -60,-120 10,-100 10,-80 -60))'));
```

Next I query the table to see if the area intersects a given polygon:

```
SELECT name, 
       ST_Intersects(ST_GeographyFromText('POLYGON((0 0,0 90,90 0,0 0))'), area) 
FROM test ORDER BY name;

 name  | st_intersects 
-------+---------------
 test1 | f
(1 row)
```

It does not intersect, as expected.
Now, I insert another row, which is identical to the first row, except for the name:

```
INSERT INTO test (name, area) 
VALUES('test2', 
        ST_GeogFromText('POLYGON((-80 -60,-100 -60,-120 -60,-120 10,-100 10,-80 -60))'));
```

Finally, I run the same query:

```
SELECT name, 
       ST_Intersects(ST_GeographyFromText('POLYGON((0 0,0 90,90 0,0 0))'), area) 
FROM test ORDER BY name;

 name  | st_intersects 
-------+---------------
 test1 | t
 test2 | f
(2 rows)
```

To my surprise, now the first row indicates that it intersects, but not the second, while the areas are identical.

Is this a bug or am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please report it to postgis. And if possible, test it with the latest versions (Postgres 13.1, not sure for Postrgis) in a new, empty db.

Comment: I can confirm that this is a bug. This eventually calls `geography_dwithin_cache` in the PostGIS code with caches sume intermediate data structures for efficiency. These cached values are used after the second time, and something in this code must be going wrong.

Comment: This appears to be the same bug as https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4727, or at least the fix for it also fixes this.  A fix has been committed, but has not yet been released.  It should be in 3.0.3.

Comment: @jjanes please post this as an answer.